# Show image from image url in xml file

Tags: android

Right now, I have a xml file which contain image url. What I want to do is to load and show those image. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use put this xml in the string.xml file and use it in the activity as getString(id of the string). and after that you can use Uri.parse(string) to get the Uri and use.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML parser to parse the Image URL. Here is an example of xml parsing http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser.
Now use the image url to load the image from web. Here is an example to load image from web. [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)